# Generate Excel sheet report fron json array in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, excel

I want to generate excel sheet report. I having JSON object that i will be converted into JSONarray. Here is my sample code

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString()); //convert to json object
JSONArray objSearchOrdersDto = jsonObj.getJSONArray("objSearchOrdersDto"); // convert to json array

for (int i = 0; i < objSearchOrdersDto.length(); ++i) 
{

    JSONObject rec = objSearchOrdersDto.getJSONObject(i);
    int OrderNumber = rec.getInt("OrderNumber");
    String strStatusType = rec.getString("strStatusType");
    int OrgUnitId = rec.getInt("OrgUnitId");
    System.out.println(OrderNumber+"\t"+strStatusType+"\t"+OrgUnitId); //want to excel file for this three field
}
```

Here i want to generate excel report only for these three field  in for loop.
Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Use Apache POI to do that

Comment: You can use Apache POI for this and use classes like XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet, Row, Cell. I have added a sample code snippet below, Please check - Mark as answered if it answers your query.

Comment: Its working, can it possible to open file in Append mode @SrikanthA . so i can continue with existing data for next time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache POI for this and use classes like XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet, Row, Cell.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString()); //convert to json object
JSONArray objSearchOrdersDto = jsonObj.getJSONArray("objSearchOrdersDto"); // convert to json array


XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");

        int rowCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < objSearchOrdersDto.length(); ++i)
        {
            JSONObject rec = objSearchOrdersDto.getJSONObject(i);
            int OrderNumber = rec.getInt("OrderNumber");
            String strStatusType = rec.getString("strStatusType");
            int OrgUnitId = rec.getInt("OrgUnitId");

            Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(1);
            cell1.setCellValue(OrderNumber);
            Cell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
            cell2.setCellValue(strStatusType);
            Cell cell3 = row.createCell(3);
            cell3.setCellValue(OrgUnitId);
            System.out.println(OrderNumber+"\t"+strStatusType+"\t"+OrgUnitId); //want to excel file for this three field
        }


        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("Report.xlsx")) {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }
```

Required Imports -

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;